# How can I create a calendar group folder in Outlook?

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

Someone knows how can we programmatically create a Root Folder in the calendar section of Outlook 2010/2013. I only can create a subfolder in my personnal calendar root folder but can't create an another root folder.

```
 private void EnsureRootFolderExists()
    {
        bool create = false;
        Folder rootStoreFolder = _app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Folder;
        try {
            _rootFolder = rootStoreFolder.Folders["Owncloud"] as Folder;
        }
        catch {
            create = true;
        }

        if (create) {
            _rootFolder = rootStoreFolder.Folders.Add("Owncloud") as Folder;
        }
        else {
            _rootFolder = rootStoreFolder.Folders["Owncloud"] as Folder;
        }
    }
```

I tried this too but it create a folder in the inbox section. Not really what i search for ...

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the type of folder.

The first parameter of the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862204.aspx) function accepts a string which contains the display name of the new folder. The second parameter accepts the OlDefaultFolders enumeration that indicates the type of folder you want to create. If the new folder type is not specified, it will default to the type of the folder in which it is created. The following values are possible for the second parameter: **olFolderCalendar**, olFolderContacts, olFolderDrafts, olFolderInbox, olFolderJournal, olFolderNotes and olFolderTasks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. But if i do like this it will create a subfolder in the **olFolderCalendar** which is the default calendar folder. I would like to be able to create an another root folder in the Calendar section. It's possible to do it trough the interface (right click : **New calendar group**). This what il would like to achieve but programmatically.